# How to redirect your users subdomain accounts to a subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

Please, I'm working on a project where I need to capture the subdomain of my website as a string and query the user database, and then display the result in another page, without altering the URL.

For instance:
If a user visits **https://kelly.domain.com.xyz**, it converts the subdomain name **"Kelly"** into a string called **id**, searches for the result and returns the query in "userpage.php?id=kelly" internally, without changing the URL https://kelly.domain.com.xyz.

What this means is that userpage.php is the hidden page for the user subdomain.

My question is, how do I rewrite the .htaccess to get the subdomain name and sends it to userpage.php

Below is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com\.xyz
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com.xyz/subdomains/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^subdomains/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$    subdomains/userpage.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Apologies if my code sucks, but I'm not so good with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Instead of htaccess use php. For php try below code to get subdomain.

```
$id = array_shift(explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

instead of url parameter, you will get direct value.